# linearGradient showing up in one color

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg

Can someone point me what is wrong in this code ?

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">@import "js/jquery.svg/jquery.svg.css";</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.svg/jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/svg.js"></script>

<body>
   <div id="svgintro" style="height:800px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var defs=svg.defs();
svg.linearGradient(defs, 'gradient', [[0, 'white', 1], [1, 'red', 1]], 0, 0, 0, 100, {gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'});
svg.rect(20, 400, 1500, 40, 10, 10, {fill:'url(#gradient)'});
```

It always show one color.

Thank you.

***Solution:***

```
svg.linearGradient(defs, 'gradient', [['0%', 'white'], ['100%', 'red']], 20, 400, 20, 440, {gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'});
```

Comment: Can you submit a jsfiddle example? Would be much easier.

Comment: Initially I tried to post an example in jsfiddle as I use a jquery svg plugin, I could not post it there. However, I have edited my original question to include the html as well. Thanks

Comment: Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/VTKj2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here, as far as I can tell, is that the `x1, y1, x2, y2` attributes of `linearGradient` are in absolute coordinates, not relative to the object you're applying the gradient to. So your gradient ends at `y:100` but the top of your rectangle is at `y:400`, so it only gets the red part of the gradient applied.

See http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/VTKj2/1/ for an example, showing that a rectangle with the top at `y:20` has the gradient properly applied.